# code 2067 SQLITE_CONSTRAINT_UNIQUE при работе с Android MediaStorage

Tags: android, android-sdk

Для сохранение файлов из приложения в загрузки используется следующий код:

```
    Uri collection = MediaStore.Downloads.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(MediaStore.Downloads.DISPLAY_NAME, filename);
    values.put(MediaStore.Downloads.MIME_TYPE, mimeType);
    values.put(MediaStore.Downloads.RELATIVE_PATH, Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
    ContentResolver contentResolver = context.getApplicationContext().getContentResolver();
    Uri uri = contentResolver.insert(collection, values);
    OutputStream outputStream = context.getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().openOutputStream(uri, "w");
```

Все сохраняется, однако если удалить файл из загрузок вручную, а потом попытаться загрузить его еще раз из приложения появляется ошибка:

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: UNIQUE constraint failed: files._data (code 2067 SQLITE_CONSTRAINT_UNIQUE[2067])
```

Возможно ли это как-то исправить или придется использовать уникальные имена для каждой загрузки?

Comment: последовательность ваших действий по подробнее: получаете uri файла через insert, затем файл удаляете вручную, далее?

Comment: @Style-7, далее инсертим тот же файл (с тем же именем, типом и т.д.) - получаем исключение. Однако если реальный файл существует, то insert проходит, молча прибавляя к имени файла номер в скобках. То есть беда случается когда запись в базе ещё есть, а реального файла уже нет.

Comment: @woesss ну вот из-за вас только время потерял: так все работает, поэтому у автора вопроса и спрашивал, что он делает, а скорее всего старый url пытается использовать

Comment: @Style-7 Вообще все происходит именно так, как описали выше. Файл удаляем вручную, потом опять допустим пытаемся сохранить его в загрузки. Пытаешься делать insert и выскакивает эта ошибка

Comment: @Style-7 если прям подробно:
Файл сохраняется в загрузки, функция завершается. После через проводник допустим удалим этот файл. Опять открываем приложение запускаем сохранение точно такого же файла. Пытаешься делать insert и выскакивает эта ошибка, но если допустим изменить название(filename), все успешно сработает

Comment: я вас понял, но вот я протестировал на 2 устройствах, Андроид 11, 12 - у меня все работает без ошибок, поэтому не могу помочь. Могу лишь посоветовать сохранять URI а потом его удалить перед записью

Comment: Да, но имя может совпасть и с чужим файлом. Генерировать уникальное имя конечно можно, но 100% гарантии не даст даже псевдослучайная абракадабра, только выглядеть будет некрасиво, а то и подозрительно. В любом случае исключения нужно обрабатывать - поэтому я предлагаю ловить его, менять имя и повторять попытку. Костыль конечно, но менеджеры гугла на славу постарались сделать работу с файлами через то место, откуда ноги торчат. Если вы используете привилегию `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` - тогда можно сделать запрос файлов с такими параметрами - если вернёт пустой курсор - можно смело сохранять.